# Sendmail Errors when Sending via PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, sendmail, php53

I'm trying to setup a new help desk program (Kayako), but I'm having problems relaying the mail to our mail server.

Here's the error I'm getting:

> sendmail[2371]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(apache): can not chdir(/var/spool/clientmqueue/): Permission denied

I changed ownership on the `clientmqueue` folder to `smmsp:apache` with the same 770 permissions as it normally has, however the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up starting from scratch, just to make sure I only had the minimal install on there, and that there weren't any conflicting packages.

SELinux was still keeping me from connecting to the external mail server, however.

I would receive warnings like this:

> [Warning]: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to mail.mydomain.com:25 (Permission denied) (Transport/StreamBuffer.php:263)

I found that I needed to allow HTTPD scripts and modules to connect to the network by setting an SELinux boolean for `httpd_can_network_connect` to `on`.

I did this by running the following command:
`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`

If you don't use the `-P` flag, the change is not saved to the policy file, and will not persist through reboots.

Just thought I'd post this for anyone else that runs into a similar issue. I believe that  `httpd_can_network_connect` not being set to `on` was causing the `sendmail` error as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the "bat book" (4th edition, page 168) the recommended permissions for the directory are:

```
chown smmsp:smmsp clientmqueue
chmod 0770 clientmqueue
```

Comment: That's what I had them set to originally, but I changed it because of the error I keep getting. I'm assuming the 'Permission denied' error was because Apache didn't have ownership. Turning off SELinux enforcement didn't help, either.

Comment: Did you reboot the machine after turning SELinux off?

Comment: [Here's how someone else solved this](http://dailyweedhound.blogspot.gr/2010/05/noqueue-syserrapache-can-not.html) *sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on*

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to try that tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail should be running `setgid`, otherwise the mail queue would have to be writable by PHP. It sounds like this is not the case on your server.

Comment: Sounds like a major security risk to me.

Comment: `-rwxr-sr-x. 1 root smmsp 839880 Jun 25 11:31 /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail`

Comment: @nojak well then, if you know what you're doing then you set it up however you want.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was any other way to get it working. I appreciate the response, but it sounds risky. If you would like to clarify why it's not a potential security risk, or if that's the only way to get it working, that would be much more appreciate than a snide remark.

Comment: Unfortunately the suggestion didn't work... Same error. Thanks again for the response, though. Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you restart sendmail after your changes?

Comment: @adamo Yeah, I restarted it.